# Checking validation against textboxes with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have some text boxes,their value is being generated from some source.Hence upon editing them if i remove the values and then I click submit button my jquery validation doesnt work
I am using this jquery.

```
$(function() {$("#error1").hide();});

$('#save').click(function() { 
         
     $('input:text').each(function(){
       if( $(this).val().length == 0)
          $("#error1").show('slow');
  
    });
});
```

Through this jquery I want to validate my all textboxes.Even my required field validator not working.This may be an old question,but I tried to find the solution,but I didnt got any valid answer to it.Please help.

Comment: You could try `html5` patterns? http://html5pattern.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function() {
    $("#error1").hide();
    $('#save').click(function() { // write this in document.ready function
        var flag=false;
        $('input:text').each(function(){
           if( $(this).val().length == 0) {
              flag=true;
              return false; //break the loop if showing common message
           }
        });
        if(flag === true) {// show error once only
             $("#error1").show('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help,but still this is bypassing the validation.I gave a alert box also to see if the code is working,for sure shot the code is working,but validation is not

Comment: can you make an online demo for it like on fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

#### Check this <kbd>[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cBMgU/23/)</kbd>

#### JQuery

```
$("#error1").hide(); 
$("#save").off().on('click', function(){   
    if($('#txtname').val().length == 0){                      
        $("#error1").show('slow');
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#error1").hide();    
    }
});
```

#### HTML

```
<input type="text" id="txtname" name="txtname">
<input type="submit" id="save" />
<p id="error1">Textbox can not be blank.!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pM4wL/

**Script**

```
$(function() {$("#error1").hide();});

$('#save').click(function() {
     validInput = true;
     $('input:text').each(function(){
         if($(this).val().length === 0) {
            validInput = false;
            $(this).addClass("input-error");
            $("#error1").show('slow');
         }
    });
    if(validInput) {
        $("#myForm").submit();
    }
});
```